# How can I set unselected indicator on TabBar?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

I'm trying to put a `TabBar` somewhere in a `Column` and have the unselected tabs appear in a different color. What I achieved so far is:

[image]

I want the green part the same size as the orange tab but only on the unselected tabs. How can that be done? I am using parameter `indicator` in `TabBar` to get the orange tab but there is no parameter `unselected`.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TabBar Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  List<Widget> _tabList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _tabController ??= _buildTabs();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TabBar Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text('Some widgets above tab bar'),
            _buildTabBar(),
            _buildTabBarView(),
            Text('Some widgets below tab bar'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TabController _buildTabs() {
    Decoration tabDecoration = BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
    );
    _tabList = [
      Container(
        decoration: tabDecoration,
        child: Tab(child: Icon(Icons.watch_later_outlined)),
      ),
      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.link_rounded)),
      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings_outlined)),
    ];
    return TabController(length: _tabList.length, vsync: this);
  }

  Widget _buildTabBar() {
    return TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      indicator: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
      tabs: _tabList,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTabBarView() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 1 * kMinInteractiveDimension,
      child: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          Text('This is tab 1'),
          Text('This is tab 2'),
          Text('This is tab 3'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output of Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.25.0-8.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.746], locale de-DE)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: You've only added decoration for the first tab.

Comment: Yes. Does it make a difference?

Comment: I have opened an enhancement request "Decoration for unselected tabs in TabBar". See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75588